# php add a css class to selected menu item

Tags: php, css, class, dynamic-data

I have a menu generated in php this way.

```
<?php 
    while($rowMenu = mysql_fetch_array($rsMenu)){
       $link="category.php?cat=".$rowMenu['MenuItemID'];
       $name = utf8_encode($rowMenu['name']);
?>                    
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><li><?php echo $name; ?></li></a>                       
<?php 
     }
?>
```

and now I want to add a background-color to the item of the present page.The background-color is defined in css ( .productActive )

I search for add a css class in php like I make with javascript but didnt find any solution, so I made this way

```
<?php 
            $cat=$_GET['cat']; /gets the id from the URL

        while($rowMenu = mysql_fetch_array($rsMenu)){
           $link="category.php?cat=".$rowMenu['MenuItemID'];
           $name = utf8_encode($rowMenu['name']);
    ?>                    
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><li><?php echo $name; ?></li></a>                       
    <?php

            if($cat == $rowMenu['MenuItemID']) {
          echo"<a href=".$link."><li class='productActive'>".$nome."</li></a>"; 
             }

         }//end of while
    ?>
```

But this way add one more item to the menu. it repeats the present li item. Is there any other way??

Thanks

Comment: Is this your exact code? If so, the PHP is malformed and you're lucky you get any output.

Comment: Consider using if/else, not just if

Comment: @ Mr. Disappointment Dont see why.its everything working fine
@Mikhail  yes. I did like you said. thanks

Comment: I agree with Mr.D. Code is poorly formatted, and jumbled together. There are several typos (like single slash for comment and nome instead of name). I foresee future errors too. julio's code below is much easier to read, even without comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($rowMenu = mysql_fetch_array($rsMenu)){
    $link="category.php?cat=".$rowMenu['MenuItemID'];
    $name = utf8_encode($rowMenu['name']);

    if($cat == $rowMenu['MenuItemID']) {
        echo"<a href=".$link."><li class='productActive'>".$name."</li></a>"; 
    } else {
        echo"<a href=".$link."><li>".$name."</li></a>";
    }
}
```

That should work, I think

Answer (score 0):

```
while($rowMenu = mysql_fetch_array($rsMenu)){
  $link = "category.php?cat=".$rowMenu['MenuItemID'];
  $name = utf8_encode($rowMenu['name']);

  // add active class?
  $class = $cat == $rowMenu['MenuItemID']
         ? ' class="productActive"'
         : '';

  ?>                    
    <li<?= $class; ?>><a href="<?= $link; ?>"><?= $name; ?></a></li>
  <?php
}//end of while
```

Then if the item matches, it'll add the class to the tag, otherwise it won't add anything.

*Although I would prefer this:*

```
printf('<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $class, $link, $name);
```

**p.s. Anchors should always be *inside* the `<li>`, not outside.**

Comment: Down vote for no reason? What was wrong about the above code?